# не открываются ссылки js

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте ! Есть сайт на котором ссылки идут через написанный код js

```
 function goPage(sPage) {
    window.location.href = sPage;
}
```

Сама ссылка в коде html выглядит так

```
  <a href="javascript:goPage('https://gaga.ru/7rCKBf2dBwc')" target="_blank">Сайт</a>
```

Во всех браузерах работает а вот в Mozille нет ? Подскажите пожалуйста как дописать или написать другой код чтоб работал в mozille ?

Comment: Вы смотрели ошибку через инструменты Web разработчика?

Comment: Так ошибки нет просто чистый лист ссылка на чистую страницу about:blank

Comment: Подскажите как это сделать ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Tools/Web_Console

Comment: Да нет там ошибок ! На этот код он вообще не ругается ! Все норм !

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="" onclick="goPage('https://gaga.ru/7rCKBf2dBwc'); return false;">Сайт</a>
```

Я бы избавился от ссылки, оформил бы под нее стилями button или span.

Comment: Господин хороший вы помогли А можно теперь это сделать чтобы в файле изменить ? Просто таких ссылок много и переделывать их это беда ?

Comment: function goPage(sPage) {
    window.location.href = sPage;}  Именно этот код как переделать А то ссылок много и их все переделывать уйдет пол года !

Comment: button или span это понятно и дело в том что если ставить оформлять как не ссылку то работает метод. А если надо картинку сделать ссылкой так не работает !?

Comment: Что на что переделать?

Comment: Если нужен переход по картинке, то вешайте onclick прямо на нее

Comment: Мне надо именно код который в файле переделать а не тот который в HTML вставляется. Ну не саму ссылку а код в js файле ? У меня около 100 ссылок таких разбросанных по сайту и не открываются а переделывать их все я умру. Хотелось бы код который в файле.js изменить function goPage(sPage) {
    window.location.href = sPage;
}

Comment: Помогите прошу !

Comment: В смысле везде по шаблонам раскидано множество href="javascript:goPage... и переделать сложно? Множество редакторов имеют возможность автоматической замены куска кода. Качаете IntelliJ IDEA, жмете ctrl+shift+F, в строке что заменить _href="javascript:goPage_, в строке на что заменить _href="" onclick="goPage_, жмете найти и заменить все

Comment: Проблема с использованием onclick="goPage исчезла Но вот только стало пере загружаться вся страница. Нажимаешь на ссылку она открывается новая вкладка этой ссылки не справа как положено а слева и перезагружает всю страницу ? Что делать ?

Comment: Проверил - перезагружается в обоих случаях. Если нужно открывать в другой вкладке, то window.open(sPage) вместо window.location.href = sPage.